# Codeignighter - Using jQuery to POST form data to my controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, post

So I am loading data into a form and the user should be able to change it and save it. The data loads fine and when the user clicks on the save button, jQuery grabs that data and should send it to my codeignighter controller, but it does not. The weird thing is that codeignighter is saying that the call was successful.

Here is my jQuery (it is in a seperate .js file):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#checkin").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var ConditionID = [];
        $('input[name^="ConditionID"]').each(function() {
            ConditionID.push($(this).val());
        });
        var Field = [];
        $('div[name^="Field"]').each(function() {
            Field.push($(this).val());
        });
        var Status = [];
        $('select[name^="Status"]').each(function() { 
            Status.push($(this).val());
        });
        var Description = [];
        $('textarea[name^="Description"]').each(function() {
            Description.push($(this).val());
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: "/index.php/ConditionReports/saveCheckin",
            type: "POST",
            data: {'ConditionID':ConditionID,'Field':Field,'Status':Status,'Description':Description},
            success:function(data)
            {
                alert('SUCCESS!!');
            },
            error:function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My view:

```
<form action='' method='post' id='checkin' accept-charset='ytf-8'>
    <?php
    $i=0;
    foreach($Conditions as $c) {
        echo("
        <input type='hidden' id='ConditionID' name='ConditionID[]' value='$c->ConditionID' />
        <div id='Field' name='Field[]' value='$c->Field'>$c->Field</div>
        <select id='Status' name='Status[]'>");
            $e=($c->Status=="E"?"selected":"");
            $g=($c->Status=="G"?"selected":"");
            $s=($c->Status=="S"?"selected":"");
            $b=($c->Status=="B"?"selected":"");
            $m=($c->Status=="M"?"selected":"");
            echo("
            <option $e value='E'>Excellent/New</option>
            <option $g value='G'>Good</option>
            <option $s value='S'>Satisfactory</option>
            <option $b value='B'>Poor/Needs Repair</option>
            <option $m value='M'>Missing</option>
        </select>
        <textarea class='form-control' name='Description[]' id='Description'>$c->Description</textarea>
        ");
        $i++;
    }
    ?>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Print</button>
<input type="submit" id="saveCheckin" value='Save' class="btn btn-success save">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Check-In</button>
</form>
```

My controller:

```
class ConditionReports extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->model('ConditionReportsVM');
        $header_data['js'] = array('jquery-2.2.1.min','checkin');
        $this->load->view('header', $header_data);
    }
    public function saveCheckin()
    {
        $data = array(
            'ConditionID' => $this->input->post('ConditionID'),
            'Field' => $this->input->post('Field'),
            'Status' => $this->input->post('Status'),
            'Description' => $this->input->post('Description'),
        );
        $this->ConditionReportsVM->UpdateReport($data);
    }
}
```

And lastly my model:

```
public function UpdateReport($data)
{
    $this->db->where('ConditionID',$data['ConditionID']);
    $this->db->update('Conditions',$data);
}
```

I have been stuck on this for quite a bit of time now and any help I can get is most appreciated. I have debugged jQuery and found out that the appropriate data is being called. There are no console errors. I have tried to echo something from the controller and I have also tried to redirect the page from the controller but the controller just seems like it is not being hit.

Thank you in advance.

Note: Currently the response I get after I click save is an alert with this in it: "SUCCESS!!"

Comment: Does it go saveCheckin action on Button click ?

Comment: Console.log your post variables before you send them with the ajax, they might be empty. If not, then var_dump the post variables inside the saveCheckin function (use network tab to see the response of the ajax to see the var_dump), and if it's there, just keep moving up and see where the data is stopped.

Comment: @Alok
What do you mean? Like if I were to change the jQuery to be something like `$("#checkin").click(function(e){` and make the `<input type="submit" id="saveCheckin"...>` a button? 

No it still does not work... Same results

Comment: I mean echo something in saveCheckin() at beginning of function and exit the script. Does it get display on the screen ?

Comment: @Alok : please correct me if im wrong, but i think that is not possible since that is an AJAX call ...  for owner, if i face similar problem, first step would be to check whether function saveCheckin() is really called, usually i would use file log, or may be console.log, and then check whether ur parameter to UpdateReport($data) is correct

Comment: @Ivan No that's possible using monitoring the network call from the browser. We can see the output of the request. You can use postman too for debugging.

Comment: @Alok, thank u for the correction

Comment: @Goose
Your answer was the most useful! I did not know you could see the response in the network tab! As soon as I went there I saw the codeighter was throwing an Array to string conversion error in my model. I fixed it and now the data is saving to the database and everything!! Thanks again! I will post my solution.

Answer (score 1):

### **SOLUTION**

Thanks to Goose (in the comments) I was able to find my issue. I did not know this, but you can see the response from the server if you go to the developer tools, and go to the Network tab. As soon as I went there I noticed that codeigniter was throwing an Array to string conversion error in my model.

Here is what my model looks like now (the data is saving and everything):

```
public function UpdateReport($data)
{
    for($i=0;$i<count($data['ConditionID']);$i++) {
        $this->db->where('ConditionID',$data['ConditionID'][$i]);
        $this->db->update('Conditions', array('Status' => $data['Status'][$i], 'Description' => $data['Description'][$i]));
    }
}
```